# How to use Trigger with joining 2 tables?

Tags: oracle

```
    I have 2 tables one is Schedule_table  :

    SID      NOT NULL       NUMBER(38)
    FNUMBER                 VARCHAR2(20)
    DEPARTURE_TIME          TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
    ARRIVAL_TIME            TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE
    PRICE                   NUMBER

    The second table is Flight_table  

    FNUMBER        NOT NULL   VARCHAR2(20)
    DEPARTURE_APCODE          CHAR(3)
    ARRIVAL_APCODE            CHAR(3)
```

Fnumber is PK in Flight_table and FK in Schedule_table.

I want the trigger to fire when the PRICE gets changed in Schedule_table
Also, to print a message of (Fnumber, ARRIVAL_APCODE, DEPARTURE_TIME ,ARRIVAL_APCODE).

I wrote this Code, it did not work.

```
create or replace trigger schedule_trigger after update on schedule
for each row  when (new. price <> old. price)

 begin
dbms_output.put_line( 'the flight number ' || :new.fnumber|| DEPARTURE_APCODE ||DEPARTURE_TIME|| ' has changed to  '||:new.price ||' From'||:old.price);
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the columns of `Flight`  table - `DEPARTURE_APCODE` and `DEPARTURE_TIME` directly inside trigger which is not possible.You need to use a select 
to fetch those values.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER schedule_trigger AFTER
    UPDATE ON schedule
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( new.price <> old.price )
DECLARE
    v_departure_apcode   flight.departure_apcode%TYPE;
    v_arrival_apcode     flight.arrival_apcode%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        departure_apcode,
        arrival_apcode
    INTO
        v_departure_apcode,v_arrival_apcode
    FROM
        flight
    WHERE
        fnumber =:new.fnumber;

    dbms_output.put_line('The flight number '
    ||:new.fnumber
    || v_departure_apcode
    || v_arrival_apcode
    || ' has changed to  '
    ||:new.price
    || ' From '
    ||:old.price);

END;
/
```

And **note** that using `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` inside a trigger is of no use as SQL developer sometimes does not display your output. Better create a log table and insert the records into it in your `trigger`.

You  may require a commit statement for the output to be displayed.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
UPDATE Schedule SET PRICE = 2502.00 where fnumber = 'F2004' ;
commit;

Commit complete.

The flight number F2004AB CD  has changed to  2502 From 2501
```